# Is it possible to use capitalization in subdomains? Or do Chrome/Firefox/Safari force subdomains to lowercase?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-chrome, firefox, cloudflare

Is there a way to set up a subdomain name with capitalization? I have a client request to create a capitalized subdomain (for branding purposes), and I am stuck on how to implement this request.

I have created A records on two separate domains with two different DNS providers (Namecheap and Cloudflare.) Both of these providers automatically lowercase the subdomain name.

[image: Cloudflare A record]
[image: Namecheap A record]

I have set up Apache 2.4.34 to handle the records:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/SUB
 ServerName SUB.communityartshow.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I have created a simple PHP script to print out the HOST:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <pre>
      <?php echo "Hello: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

As expected, the subdomain resolves correctly -- but even if I type in the subdomain in uppercase, it gets converted to lowercase in Chrome and Firefox:

[image: Chrome subdomain request]
[image: Firefox subdomain request]

I believe the issue is a browser issue. I can edit the request headers in Firefox to force the uppercase subdomain, but it still comes back lowercase:

[image: Firefox - edit request headers]

Lastly, when using CURL on the subdomain, I'm able to successfully see the capitalized subdomain:

[image: CURL request allowing capitalized subdomains]

My question:
Is it possible to configure the subdomain to show capitalization in the browser? Or are browsers forcing lowercase now? I use Apache, but if it's possible with other web servers, I would be very interested to hear that.

I have considered that this could be solved using Apache http.conf or .htaccess directives -- but since it seems to work in CURL, that seems like a dead end. Am I wrong in this assumption? My googling is only showing me "uppercase to lowercase" URL rewrites, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm sure that all browsers encode and normalise the URLs you type (the most obvious manipulation is to add the `http://` protocol prefix, and often even a `www.` subdomain). This whole effort looks pretty much pointless; would your client be fine with distributing custom browser forks to all his visitors?

Comment: It's not an issue: DNS is case-insensitive, so any client is free to do whatever they want with regards to capitalization. So what you call issue is just normal and legal behavior of the browsers.

Comment: @OlafKock Thanks for your comment. I understand this is normal behaviour for browsers; that subdomains are case insensitive. I'm simply trying to figure out of it's possible to show uppercase subdomains in browsers.

Comment: @OlafKock That is only partially correct. Yes, one can type (or copy or click) an uppercase host name and the name resolution will work. But as far as I can tell all standard browsers convert such host name to lowercase in the visible URL bar. Which is exactly what the question is about: whether it is possible to _keep_ the uppercase name visible. Which is _not_ possible to my knowledge.